# Access the Topology of the Dwarf Fortress World?

Tags: dwarf-fortress

**Is there anyone way to access the topographical map created during world generation?**

During in-game play it is easy to see if a piece of outside land is up-slope or down-slope. And in-game you can easily view higher and lower levels in your mountain fortress. What I need is some way to access information on the topology of the generated world. This would allow me to create a 3D map (think Minecraft or Oblivion) of the outside world.

For the moment, I don't care if the game is playable in this way. Don't worry about that. I just want to be able to see these wonderful worlds I am generating.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Start a new game in the "Legends" mode. This allows you to export a multitude of detailed information about the world, among them detailed maps using the [d] key. The options "Elevations including lake and ocean floors" and "Elevations respecting water level" both produce heightmaps of the world while the other options allow you to export a texture to match it.

[image]
[image]

The graphics are exported into the base Dwarf Fortress directory (the same one where `DwarfFortress.exe`resides), under the names ...

- `world_graphic-el-`*region name*`-`*some numbers*`.bmp` for the "elevation including lake and ocean floors" map
- `world_graphic-elw-`*region name*`-`*some numbers*`.bmp` for the "elevation respecting water level" map

For the highest size region (257x257), they are 4112x4112px in size. They look like this, scaled down (in order: with lake/ocean floors, with water level):

[image]
[image]

Comment: Thanks so much! These are great surface maps. Is there any way to get maps of the below-the-surface information, like the levels of your fortress, on a map of some/any kind? (Or is that hoping too much?)

Comment: @theJollySin: Not with in-game tools, but obviously memory hacking allows you to view all of the in-game map ... but only of the loaded area (which is really small, compared to the whole world). The main tool for such is [DFHack](http://www.bay12forums.com/smf/index.php?topic=91166.0), which includes the Stonesense isometric visualiser nowadays.